# Has anyone ever been expelled from Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts, behavior

Reading through the Code of Conduct, the tours, etc., I noticed that people could have their accounts expelled! I thought this was fairly severe and, thus, wanted to know whether it had happened before. Since this is a fairly personal question, I don't need names of users or anything. I just want to know whether it is happened (I also don't need a why).

> [image: expulsion]

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: @fbueckert Curiosity... pure curiosity...

Comment: I'm not sure there's going to be any good discussion on this; more just gossip about who and why.  I don't think that's very constructive.

Comment: Lots and lots of spammers have had and continue to have their accounts removed

Comment: @fbueckert It is Friday, anything goes ...

Comment: "Hi, has this bank ever pressed charges against a robber? I'm asking for a friend."

Comment: @TimPost It is a very valid question to ask whether the bank has been robbed before... I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: If someone  "presses charges" it means that they have reported a crime to the police and they want the person charged with the crime to be prosecuted or held accountable. In Tim's joke, it's not asking whether a bank has been victim of a robbery. The speaker (a potential robber) who is asking on behalf of a "friend" really wants to know if they get caught robbing the bank, will they be charged and prosecuted for the crime.

Comment: @RobertLongson surely what OP posted is not about spammers. It's about ordinary users like you or me, who over time get repeated warnings and are eventually expelled from the site. Totally valid question, though for most active users the answer is clear. (Which is "Yes, it happens.")

Comment: @ShaWiz... Thanks, that's exactly right!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We don't have a feature on the site called "expel". But yes, accounts do occasionally get deleted for reasons listed below, and we occasionally block IP addresses from locations receiving chronic abuse; yes.

> ⚪ delete
> <sub>Deletes this user account, denormalizes identity on any posts they own, and deletes any negatively voted posts they own. Does not delete any content scored 0 or higher.</sub>
>
> > ⚪ This user was created to circumvent system or moderator imposed restrictions and continues to contribute poorly
> > ⚪ This user is a sock puppet of: (select one or more puppet masters)
> > ⚪ This user is no longer welcome to participate on the site
> > ⚪ This user requested deletion while logged into the site
>
> ⚪ destroy
> <sub>Deletes this user account and deletes all content they own. Only usable on users with less than 500 reputation.</sub>
>
> > ⚪ This user was created to post spam or nonsense and has no other positive participation
> > ⚪ The vast majority of all content contributed by this user violates our terms of service

Comment: I put a picture in my question to show you where I got the word ***"expel"*** from...

Comment: @INTERESTING It could just have easily been phrased as "Termination" "Ban" - there are many words for hitting that intersection where the site goes on without a particular user being part of it. The code of conduct (the source of your excerpt) has to use language that anyone without experience with the site will understand, and expulsion is quite unambiguous.

Comment: @TimPost Sure, but I just wanted to point it out. BTW all those other words are fairly ambiguous as well...